# how can i install beautiful soup in the centOS server

Tags: terminal, centos, beautifulsoup

I just got a new  hostserver from hostgator which has centOS. Now I have a webscraping program written in the python which imports from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

how can i install beautiful soup in the centOS server?

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it via `setuptools`:

```
easy_install beautifulsoup4
```

Or, if you have `pip` installed:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

In case you are using system python, you need to run it with `sudo`.

Or, if you are using system python, you can install it via `yum`:

```
sudo yum install python-beautifulsoup4
```

If, nothing worked at this point for whatever reason, you can always [download the package](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download) and install it manually, for example:

```
$ wget http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.3/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz 
$ cd beautifulsoup4-4.3.2
$ python setup.py install
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Manual installation is the best way to do. When you don't have control of system. Like when you are not root and also when you cannot use "yum" or "apt-get".

Thank you for your solution. :-)